# Symfony reset password with multiple entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to implement reset password for my project.
I have 2 types of users that can login to my app, they each have their own entity.
I use the reset-password-bundle that works well for one entity but I can't make it work for the 2.

I read this page : https://github.com/SymfonyCasts/reset-password-bundle/issues/110

They give a bit of an answer but I can't implement it.
I tried to add an extra field with the other entity to the ResetPasswordRequest but I just end up with 2 'null' fields in the database.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

according to what I have learned you don't need a password reset bundle it's way too complicated. add a string field in entity and name it resetkey. for password reset make a public form with the key field you are using for entity for example its email. the user will fill email and submit form once form is submitted in controller check if email exist in the database or not. is email exist then make random/unique string and set it in resetkey field of entity and send email to the user with a link with resetkey. once the user clicks on the link with resetkey the user will be sent to your website. in the controller part of reset link find the entry with the resekey in the entity and return another form for password. on form submit validate password and apply encoding you are using and set it to the entity and flush the entity manager. and your password will successfully changed

Comment: Have you ever implemented such functionality?  You have the right idea but some of the steps can be a bit involved.  It is partially why the reset bundle is so over engineered.

Comment: yes i have implemented this functionality a lot of time. and its not that hard.